# Google Maps with Flash as3 - change web address

Tags: actionscript-3, api, google-maps, actionscript

My as3 google map is depreciated but still works unless I change my URL

www.mydomain.com    =>     www2.mydomain.com

Since I cannot create a new key what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

#### Obtaining a Maps API Key

The Maps API for Flash is officially deprecated, but will continue to be supported for existing applications in accordance with the deprecation policy defined in the [Maps API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). Consequently we recommend against using the Maps API for Flash in any new applications, and instead recommend use of the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript).

Although we are no longer issuing keys for the Maps API for Flash, we understand that some existing developers may need to update the key being used for an existing application, for example due to a change of hostname. Please follow the instructions on the [Maps API for Flash Key Request website](https://flash-maps-key-request.appspot.com/) if you need a new key.

The Google Maps API for Flash, like the Google JavaScript Maps API, requires usage of a key. You will need to specify this key within one of three possible locations:

- (For Flex applications) A special configuration file called an `MXML` declaration
- (For Flash applications) Your ActionScript code (compiling it into the resulting SWF file)
- The containing DOM element in your web page.

Note that the API key is compiled into the `SWF` file and must match the domain where the `SWF` file is hosted, which may not necessarily be the location for the hosted HTML file. This document set will show Flex examples defining the API key within the MXML declarations.

#### I believe this portion of what's stated above pertains to you:

Although we are no longer issuing keys for the Maps API for Flash, we understand that some existing developers may need to update the key being used for an existing application, for example due to a change of hostname. Please follow the instructions on the [Maps API for Flash Key Request website](https://flash-maps-key-request.appspot.com/) if you need a new key.


[Original Q&A from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/intro#API_Key)